# Route to Existing Layout

Tags: category, layout, routing, router, routes

I am working on a custom page module and want to make a custom route however I would like to use the catalog_category_view.xml layout, instead of the [module_name]_index_index.xml needed for my route to work.

Is there a way to configure my module to use to catalog_category_view.xml?

Side note, I would also like to use a custom block to send a specific collection to list.phtml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend copy the content of catalog_category_view.xml to your layout in your custom  module instead of modify the routing. Here you can use your own Block to send a specific collection to list.phtml.

Let's give it a try, if you have any issues, feel free to let us know.

Comment: hey I stuck in category search criteria API related. can you help me? https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/361393/93504

Comment: @HarshPatel I'll check.